# Center caption in standalone documentclass

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I would like to know how I can go about automatically centering the plots subcaptions in the standalone environment.  This is what I would like:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{0,173,239} %  mybluei Blue color
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, matrix, backgrounds}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.12,
    every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
    every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.8pt},
    minor grid style={dashed,red},
    major grid style={dotted,green!50!black},
    }

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont={color=ocre,scriptsize,it,bf},textfont={color=ocre,scriptsize,it,bf},labelformat=parens,labelsep=space}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\setcaptionsubtype
\begin{groupplot}[%
            ,group style={%
                ,group name=my plots
                ,group size=1 by 2
                ,vertical sep=2cm,
                ,horizontal sep = 2cm,
                ,ylabels at=edge left
            }
            ,width=10cm
            ,height=5cm
            ,try min ticks=5
            ,xlabel={\bfseries{\emph{\footnotesize{Time (ms)}}}}
            ,ylabel={\bfseries{\emph{\footnotesize{Temperature (Deg C)}}}}
            ,grid=both
            ,every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}
            ]
\nextgroupplot%
\addplot[cyan]{rand};\label{plots:ltone}

\nextgroupplot%
\addplot[cyan]{rand};\label{plots:lttwo}

\addplot [smooth,red,thick]{rand};

\end{groupplot}

\node[text width=.5\linewidth,align=center,anchor=south] at (my plots c1r1.north) {\caption[]{Lock Time Response\label{subplot:ltone}}};
\node[text width=.5\linewidth,align=center,anchor=south] at (my plots c1r2.north) {\caption[]{Zoomed-In Lock Time Response\label{subplot:lttwo}}};

\end{tikzpicture}
%\caption[]{This is a test Plot.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `node` for the caption is centered, but the caption itself is a bit left aligned. Adding `justification=centering` to your `\captionsetup` fixes that, but I don't know if that will mess up any of your other subfigure captions.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. To limit the effect to this very figure one could place `\captionsetup{justification=centering}` right after `\setcaptionsubtype`.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Thanks! I'll add an answer then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see by adding `draw` to the `node` options, the `node` containing the caption is positioned correctly, but the alignment of the caption inside  the node is wrong.

[image]

The caption alignment can be changed by the `justification` key in `\captionsetup`, i.e. `\captionsetup{justification=centering}`. Presumably you don't want all the captions in the document centered, but by adding `\captionsetup{justification=centering}` right after `\setcaptionsubtype` it will be local to the `tikzpicture` (as mentioned by Axel Sommerfeldt in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286244/center-caption-in-standalone-documentclass?noredirect=1#comment692729_286244)).

One additional note: Neither `\bfseries` nor `\footnotesize` are commands that take an argument, the way `\emph` is used. They are both switches that affect the following text, and as such should be used as `{\bfseries\footnotesize text}`

Complete code and output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{0,173,239} %  mybluei Blue color
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, matrix, backgrounds}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.12,
    every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
    every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.8pt},
    minor grid style={dashed,red},
    major grid style={dotted,green!50!black},
    }

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont={color=ocre,scriptsize,it,bf},textfont={color=ocre,scriptsize,it,bf},labelformat=parens,labelsep=space}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\setcaptionsubtype
\captionsetup{justification=centering} % <-- added
\begin{groupplot}[%
            ,group style={%
                ,group name=my plots
                ,group size=1 by 2
                ,vertical sep=2cm,
                ,horizontal sep = 2cm,
                ,ylabels at=edge left
            }
            ,width=10cm
            ,height=5cm
            ,try min ticks=5
            ,xlabel={\bfseries\footnotesize\emph{Time (ms)}}
            ,ylabel={\bfseries\footnotesize\emph{Temperature (Deg C)}}
            ,grid=both
            ,every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}
            ]
\nextgroupplot%
\addplot[cyan]{rand};\label{plots:ltone}

\nextgroupplot%
\addplot[cyan]{rand};\label{plots:lttwo}

\addplot [smooth,red,thick]{rand};

\end{groupplot}

\node[text width=.5\linewidth,align=center,anchor=south] at (my plots c1r1.north) {\caption[]{Lock Time Response\label{subplot:ltone}}};
\node[text width=.5\linewidth,align=center,anchor=south] at (my plots c1r2.north) {\caption[]{Zoomed-In Lock Time Response\label{subplot:lttwo}}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[]{This is a test Plot.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```